# What is CoreSimulator running and take up so much processing time?

Tags: macos, security, catalina

This question might belong in the Information Security space. But since it's specific to macOS, I thought I'd start here. Please comment with your recommendation if you have an opinion about it.

I've recently noticed a rogue device on my network, "iphone-4", and I have also noticed that CoreSimulator and SimulatorTrampoline have been running and taking up a large portion of processing time.

My ISP has identified my IP address as the source of attacks on their network.

[image]

***What's going on here?***

I'm not running Xcode or any iPhone simulators; or rather, I've not initiated any simulator.